# Error running a nodejs server on a Mac, 'no suitable image found'

Tags: javascript, macos, node.js, webserver, nowjs-sockets

```
unknown406c8f2d5ecb:proves airrider3$ node tronServer.js
[Error: dlopen(/Users/airrider3/Documents/proves/node_modules/now/node_modules/node-proxy/build/Release/nodeproxy.node, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/airrider3/Documents/proves/node_modules/now/node_modules/node-proxy/build/Release/nodeproxy.node: unknown file type, first eight bytes: 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x02 0x01 0x01 0x00]
Error: dlopen(/Users/airrider3/Documents/proves/node_modules/now/node_modules/node-proxy/build/Release/nodeproxy.node, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/airrider3/Documents/proves/node_modules/now/node_modules/node-proxy/build/Release/nodeproxy.node: unknown file type, first eight bytes: 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x02 0x01 0x01 0x00
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:485:11)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
    at require (module.js:378:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/airrider3/Documents/proves/node_modules/now/node_modules/node-proxy/lib/node-proxy.js:1:90)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

It worked perfectly in Linux. I've just installed nodejs, nowjs, etc, runned this server script, but it keeps throwing this error.

Any ideas?

Server code: (it's kind of a tron multiplayer game)

```
var html = require('fs').readFileSync(__dirname + '/tronMultiplayer.html');
var server = require('http').createServer(function (req, res) {
   res.end(html);
});
server.listen(8004);

var nowjs = require('now');
var everyone = nowjs.initialize(server);

var bikes = {};
var killCount = {};
var player = 0;

var EMPTY = -1;
var WALL = -2;

var map = [];
var edge = 100;

var count = 0;
var deadbikes = 0;

var gameON = false;




function resetGame () {

    map = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < edge; i++){
        map.push([]);
        for (var j = 0; j < edge; j++){
            if (i == 0 || j == 0 || i == edge-1 || j == edge-1/* || Math.floor(Math.random()*30) == 0*/){
                map[i].push(WALL);
            } else {
                map[i].push(EMPTY);
            }
        }
    }   

    for (var i in bikes){
        spawnBike(i)
    }   
    everyone.now.reset(edge);
    everyone.now.updateScores(bikes);
}

nowjs.on('connect', function () {
   console.log('connect');
   bikes[this.user.clientId] = {nick: "Anonymous", w:0, i: Math.floor(Math.random()*edge-2)+1, j: Math.floor(Math.random()*edge-2)+1, di : 0, dj : 1, p: player, c: "rgba("+Math.floor(Math.random()*255)+ ", " + Math.floor(Math.random()*255)+","+Math.floor(Math.random()*255)+", 1)", alive : false};
   killCount[this.user.clientId] = 0;
   player++;
   console.log(this.user.clientId);
   console.log(bikes);
   if (!gameON){
    gameON = true;
    resetGame();
    step();
   }
});

everyone.now.changeBikeDirection = function (dir) {
    console.log(bikes[this.user.clientId].nick + " changes his direction to " + dir);
    var ndi = 0, ndj = 0;
    if (dir == "left"){
        ndj = -1;
    } else if (dir == "right"){
        ndj = 1;
    } else if (dir == "up"){
        ndi = -1;
    } else if (dir == "down"){
        ndi = 1;
    }
    var odi, odj;
    odi = bikes[this.user.clientId].di;
    odj = bikes[this.user.clientId].dj;

    if (odi != ndi && odj != ndj) {
        bikes[this.user.clientId].di = ndi; 
        bikes[this.user.clientId].dj = ndj;
    }
    killCount[this.user.clientId] = 0; 
};

everyone.now.updateNickname = function (theName) {
    bikes[this.user.clientId].nick = theName;
    everyone.now.updateScores(bikes);
};

function spawnBike (k) {
    bikes[k].i =  Math.floor(Math.random()*edge*(2/4) -2)+1 + edge/4;
    bikes[k].j = Math.floor(Math.random()*edge*(2/4)  -2)+1 + edge/4;
    bikes[k].di = 0;
    bikes[k].dj = 1;
    bikes[k].alive = true;
    player++;
}

nowjs.on('disconnect', function () {
   console.log(bikes[this.user.clientId].nick + ' has disconnected.');
   for (var i in bikes) {
      if (i === this.user.clientId) {
         killBike(i);
     delete bikes[i];
         break;
      }
   }
});

function killBike(k){
        var bike = bikes[k];
    bike.alive = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < edge; i++){
        for (var j = 0; j < edge; j++){
            if (map[i][j] == bike.player){
                map[i][j] = EMPTY;
            }
        }
    }
    //delete bikes[k];
}

function checkIfBikeIsDead(k){
        //console.log("CheckIfBikeIsDead with id "+k);
    var bike = bikes[k];
    if (bike.alive){
        //console.log("Checking current position");
        if (map[bike.i][bike.j] != EMPTY){
            //console.log("Ouch, Cell was "+map[bike.i][bike.j]);
            bike.i -= bike.di;
            bike.j -= bike.dj;
            killBike(k);

            for (var i in bikes){
                if (i != k){
                    if (bikes[i].alive){
                        bikes[i].w++;
                    }
                }
            }
            everyone.now.updateScores(bikes);           
            return true;
        } else {
            //console.log("Safe and sound");
            map[bike.i][bike.j] = bike.p;
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}

function traceMap() {
    console.log("---------------------------------------------------------------------");
    var s = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < edge; i++){
        s = "[";
        for (var j = 0; j < edge; j++){
            if (map[i][j] == undefined){
                console.log("We found an undefined at ("+i+","+j+")");
            } else {
                s += map[i][j].toString() + ", ";
            }
        }
        s += "]";
        console.log(s);
    }
}

function step () {

    count = 0;
    deadbikes = 0;

    for (var k in bikes){
        killCount[k]++;
        if (killCount[k] > 2000){
            killBike(k);
            delete bikes[k];
        } else {
            count++;
            if (bikes[k].alive){
                bikes[k].i += bikes[k].di;
                bikes[k].j += bikes[k].dj;
                if (checkIfBikeIsDead(k)){
                    deadbikes++;
                }
            } else {
                deadbikes++;
            }
        }
    }

    if (count > 0){
        if (count == deadbikes){
        resetGame();
        }
        setTimeout(step, 50);
        everyone.now.receiveNewPositions(bikes);
    //  traceMap();
    } else {
        gameON = false;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Nevermind. Facepalm. The node_modules folder I had was the same that I used/installed in Linux, so I believe that some parts were compiled specifically for Linux, or whatever.

Solved by erasing the node_modules folder and reinstalling.

I hope it helps to anyone with the same doubt!

Comment: I'm having same issue... you reinstalled each module with Mac version, correct? So did your node project not have a node_modules folder, just used them from the global Mac install?

Comment: I didn't use the global Mac install for this project (I didn't even know it existed back then...). I just installed the modules again in the same root as the project, and it worked. I hope you manage to solve your issue!

Answer (score 16):

Follow David Da Silva Contín's answer is great!

```
$ sudo rm -rf node_modules/
$ npm install
```

Comment: slight tweak -- `git rm -rf node_modules` :)